# iOS: AVSpeechSynthesizer : need to speak text in Headphone left channel

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, text-to-speech

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer for TextToSpeech. I have to play the speak in HeadPhone left Channel (Mono 2). I have got the following to set the output channel.

```
func initalizeSpeechForRightChannel(){     
    let avSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let route = avSession.currentRoute
    let outputPorts = route.outputs
    var channels:[AVAudioSessionChannelDescription] = []
    //NSMutableArray *channels = [NSMutableArray array];
    var leftAudioChannel:AVAudioSessionChannelDescription? = nil
    var leftAudioPortDesc:AVAudioSessionPortDescription? = nil 
    for  outputPort in outputPorts {
        for channel in outputPort.channels! {
            leftAudioPortDesc = outputPort
            //print("Name: \(channel.channelName)")
            if channel.channelName == "Headphones Left" {
                channels.append(channel)
                leftAudioChannel = channel
            }else {
               // leftAudioPortDesc?.channels?.removeObject(channel)
            }
        }
    }

    if channels.count > 0 {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            print("Setting Left Channel")
            speechSynthesizer.outputChannels = channels
            print("Checking output channel : \(speechSynthesizer.outputChannels?.count)")

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```

**I have 2 problems in the code**

**1. Cant able to set outputchannels , It always nil (It is happening on first time calling this method, consecutive calls working fine)**

**2. outputchannels supports from iOS 10.* But I need to support it from iOS 
8.0**

Please provide the best way to do that.

Comment: speechSynthesizer.outputChannels = channels
After this line I tried to print the outputChannels counts it prints 0. But the object channels has one object

Comment: "Cant able to set outputchannels , It always nil" ---

On very first time , it is nil, After calling again and again it is working

Comment: One small comment — channelName may return language-sensitive (localized) text, so your 'if channel.channelName == "Headphones Left"' isn't reliable to find left channel

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of checking the `channelName`, which is descriptive (i.e. for the user), check the `channelLabel`.  [There is an enumeration containing the left channel](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreaudio/core_audio_data_types/1572103-audio_channel_label_constants).
2. I suspect this may not be possible pre-iOS 10.  <s>AVAudioSession doesn't appear to have any method to select only the left output channel.</s> You *may* be able to use [`overrideAudioPort:error`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616443-overrideoutputaudioport?language=objc) but it would affect the entire app.

Comment: Seems like there's no any useful option regarding left/right channel in the AVAudioSessionPortOverride constants.

Comment: Taking a second look that's correct.  @sridhar probably will need to look at another TTS engine that would let you play the speech via AVAudioPlayer where you have control over pan.  We used to use Google's TTS engine via AVAudioPlayer, so you might start looking there.  I don't know if it's still available.